# How to install updated Python on Mac OS Sierra with brew?

Tags: python, macos, installation, homebrew

I'm running macOS Sierra Version 10.12.2 and am trying to install a separate version of Python from the system preinstalled Python 2.7.10. I have been advised to install a new version of Python or else risk screwing up the system Python install.

I've installed Python 2.7.13 using `brew`:

```
brew install python
```

However, my terminal still defaults to the system install

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 30 2016, 19:40:32) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

What is the preferred way to install an updated (non-system) version of Python 2.7 and have the OS recognize and default to the new (2.7.13) version?

Edit:

When I update the `.bash_profile` file with the following, I get an error when starting up the bash terminal.

```
PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin:${PATH}"
export "$PATH"
```

This is the error I receive:

```
-bash: export: `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin': not a valid identifier
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just update the `$PATH` variable to point to the latest version of `Python 2.7.13` in `.bashrc` (or) `.bash_profile` depending the shell you are invoking,

```
export PATH="/path/to/your/python2.7.13/bin:${PATH}"
```

i.e. something like `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/`, i.e.

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7.13/bin:${PATH}"
```

Comment: Looks like `brew` installs python at `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python2.7`

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Python using Home Brew then do this:

```
brew upgrade python
```

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes, just trying in a new shell helps.

I did this same thing just now, and it showed me that python 2.7.10 is on my system. But I opened a new shell and tried, and voila! It was the correct version of python.

```
$ brew install python
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/python-2.7.13.sierra.bottle.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/sptamhan/Library/Caches/Homebrew/python-2.7.13.sierra.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Pouring python-2.7.13.sierra.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Using the sandbox
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --single-version-externally-managed --record=installed.txt --install-scripts=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin --install-lib=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --single-version-externally-managed --record=installed.txt --install-scripts=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin --install-lib=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --single-version-externally-managed --record=installed.txt --install-scripts=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin --install-lib=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
==> Caveats
Pip and setuptools have been installed. To update them
  pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

You can install Python packages with
  pip install <package>

They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

See: http://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python.html
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13: 3,526 files, 48MB
$ python -V
Python 2.7.10
```

In a new terminal:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.13
```